# Changes made on record by trigger after update in DB aren't visible by hibernate with findOne and findById

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I'm using in my project Spring boot 1.5.22, Spring data and Hibernate 5.2.18.
When I save my Entity object using Dao with:

```
platDao.save(plat);
```

in database is executing trigger of type BEFORE INSERT which is inserting a number of document in databse field. When I make a select from table in database with SQL in my database tool I can see value in this field. But when I get this record using hibernate with findOne method I see null in this field:

```
Platnosc plat = platDao.findOne(platId);
```

I tried also this:

```
Platnosc plat = platDao.findById(platId);
```

But result is the same, field which is set by trigger is null.

Code of my Service:

```
public List<Platnosc> createDocumentForInvoice(Integer fakturaId) {

    AuthUser user = loginMgr.getLoggedUser();

    Platnosc plat = Platnosc.builder()
            // I don't set field platnoscNr here it is null
            .build();

    platDao.save(plat);

    return plat;
}
```

Code of my controller:

```
public Response createDocumentForInvoice(
        @RequestParam(value = "fakturaId", required = true) Integer fakturaId) {

    List<Platnosc> platList = platMgr.createDocumentForInvoice(fakturaId);

    // after this I can see in database value of field platnoscNr which was inserted by trigger

    String platNr = platList.stream()
            .map(p -> {
                Platnosc plat = platDao.findById(p.getPlatnoscId());     
                return String.format("%s nr %s",
                        platMgr.getRodzajTextForPlatnoscRodzaj(plat.getPlatnoscRodzaj()),
                        plat.getPlatnoscNr());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));

    return Response.ok(platList.size() == 0
            ? "No document was created"
            : "Created documents: " + platNr)
            .build();
}
```

Response is:

"Created documents: CREDIT CARD nr null, TRANSFER nr null, OTHER PAYMENT nr null"

my DEGUG.log:

```
    // ....
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - insert into PLATNOSC (BANK_ID, EMPLOYEE_ID, FAKTURA_ID, FAKTURA_ID1, FIRMA_ID, GRUPA_ID, KASA_ID, MELDUNEK_ID, OSOBA_ID, PLATNOSC_DATA, PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY, PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID, PLATNOSC_FK_NR, PLATNOSC_FORPLA, PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU, PLATNOSC_KWOTA, PLATNOSC_NR, PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY, PLATNOSC_OPIS, PLATNOSC_PREFIX, PLATNOSC_RODZAJ, PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID, PLATNOSC_STATUS, PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE, PLATNOSC_USED, PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID, PLATONLINE_ID, POKOJ_ID, RACHOTW_ID, REZERWACJA_ID, WALUTA_ID, ZALICZKA_ID, ZMIANA_ID, PLATNOSC_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - select platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOSC1_90_, platnosc0_.BANK_ID as BANK_ID2_90_, platnosc0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID as FAKTURA_4_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1 as FAKTURA_5_90_, platnosc0_.FIRMA_ID as FIRMA_ID6_90_, platnosc0_.GRUPA_ID as GRUPA_ID7_90_, platnosc0_.KASA_ID as KASA_ID8_90_, platnosc0_.MELDUNEK_ID as MELDUNEK9_90_, platnosc0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_I10_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA as PLATNOS11_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY as PLATNOS12_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID as PLATNOS13_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FK_NR as PLATNOS14_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FORPLA as PLATNOS15_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU as PLATNOS16_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KWOTA as PLATNOS17_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NR as PLATNOS18_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY as PLATNOS19_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_OPIS as PLATNOS20_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_PREFIX as PLATNOS21_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ as PLATNOS22_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID as PLATNOS23_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STATUS as PLATNOS24_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE as PLATNOS25_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_USED as PLATNOS26_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOS27_90_, platnosc0_.PLATONLINE_ID as PLATONL28_90_, platnosc0_.POKOJ_ID as POKOJ_I29_90_, platnosc0_.RACHOTW_ID as RACHOTW30_90_, platnosc0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWA31_90_, platnosc0_.WALUTA_ID as WALUTA_32_90_, platnosc0_.ZALICZKA_ID as ZALICZK33_90_, platnosc0_.ZMIANA_ID as ZMIANA_34_90_ from PLATNOSC platnosc0_ where platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - select platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOSC1_90_, platnosc0_.BANK_ID as BANK_ID2_90_, platnosc0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID as FAKTURA_4_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1 as FAKTURA_5_90_, platnosc0_.FIRMA_ID as FIRMA_ID6_90_, platnosc0_.GRUPA_ID as GRUPA_ID7_90_, platnosc0_.KASA_ID as KASA_ID8_90_, platnosc0_.MELDUNEK_ID as MELDUNEK9_90_, platnosc0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_I10_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA as PLATNOS11_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY as PLATNOS12_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID as PLATNOS13_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FK_NR as PLATNOS14_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FORPLA as PLATNOS15_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU as PLATNOS16_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KWOTA as PLATNOS17_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NR as PLATNOS18_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY as PLATNOS19_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_OPIS as PLATNOS20_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_PREFIX as PLATNOS21_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ as PLATNOS22_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID as PLATNOS23_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STATUS as PLATNOS24_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE as PLATNOS25_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_USED as PLATNOS26_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOS27_90_, platnosc0_.PLATONLINE_ID as PLATONL28_90_, platnosc0_.POKOJ_ID as POKOJ_I29_90_, platnosc0_.RACHOTW_ID as RACHOTW30_90_, platnosc0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWA31_90_, platnosc0_.WALUTA_ID as WALUTA_32_90_, platnosc0_.ZALICZKA_ID as ZALICZK33_90_, platnosc0_.ZMIANA_ID as ZMIANA_34_90_ from PLATNOSC platnosc0_ where platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - select platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOSC1_90_, platnosc0_.BANK_ID as BANK_ID2_90_, platnosc0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID as FAKTURA_4_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1 as FAKTURA_5_90_, platnosc0_.FIRMA_ID as FIRMA_ID6_90_, platnosc0_.GRUPA_ID as GRUPA_ID7_90_, platnosc0_.KASA_ID as KASA_ID8_90_, platnosc0_.MELDUNEK_ID as MELDUNEK9_90_, platnosc0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_I10_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA as PLATNOS11_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY as PLATNOS12_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID as PLATNOS13_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FK_NR as PLATNOS14_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FORPLA as PLATNOS15_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU as PLATNOS16_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KWOTA as PLATNOS17_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NR as PLATNOS18_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY as PLATNOS19_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_OPIS as PLATNOS20_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_PREFIX as PLATNOS21_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ as PLATNOS22_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID as PLATNOS23_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STATUS as PLATNOS24_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE as PLATNOS25_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_USED as PLATNOS26_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOS27_90_, platnosc0_.PLATONLINE_ID as PLATONL28_90_, platnosc0_.POKOJ_ID as POKOJ_I29_90_, platnosc0_.RACHOTW_ID as RACHOTW30_90_, platnosc0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWA31_90_, platnosc0_.WALUTA_ID as WALUTA_32_90_, platnosc0_.ZALICZKA_ID as ZALICZK33_90_, platnosc0_.ZMIANA_ID as ZMIANA_34_90_ from PLATNOSC platnosc0_ where platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1=?
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-10-10 17:29:33 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
    // here is findById() method called
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@6f808572]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - select platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOSC1_90_, platnosc0_.BANK_ID as BANK_ID2_90_, platnosc0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID as FAKTURA_4_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1 as FAKTURA_5_90_, platnosc0_.FIRMA_ID as FIRMA_ID6_90_, platnosc0_.GRUPA_ID as GRUPA_ID7_90_, platnosc0_.KASA_ID as KASA_ID8_90_, platnosc0_.MELDUNEK_ID as MELDUNEK9_90_, platnosc0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_I10_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA as PLATNOS11_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY as PLATNOS12_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID as PLATNOS13_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FK_NR as PLATNOS14_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FORPLA as PLATNOS15_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU as PLATNOS16_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KWOTA as PLATNOS17_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NR as PLATNOS18_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY as PLATNOS19_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_OPIS as PLATNOS20_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_PREFIX as PLATNOS21_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ as PLATNOS22_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID as PLATNOS23_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STATUS as PLATNOS24_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE as PLATNOS25_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_USED as PLATNOS26_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOS27_90_, platnosc0_.PLATONLINE_ID as PLATONL28_90_, platnosc0_.POKOJ_ID as POKOJ_I29_90_, platnosc0_.RACHOTW_ID as RACHOTW30_90_, platnosc0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWA31_90_, platnosc0_.WALUTA_ID as WALUTA_32_90_, platnosc0_.ZALICZKA_ID as ZALICZK33_90_, platnosc0_.ZMIANA_ID as ZMIANA_34_90_ from PLATNOSC platnosc0_ where platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Creating new transaction with name [ekoncept.service.PlatnoscServiceImpl.getRodzajTextForPlatnoscRodzaj]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@5cc07ca4]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - select stale0_.STALE_ID as STALE_ID1_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_CENTRUM_PRZYCH as STALE_CE2_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_KOD_SYSTEMU as STALE_KO3_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_KONTOKSIEGOWE_ID as STALE_KO4_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_NAZWA as STALE_NA5_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_RODZAJ_ID as STALE_RO6_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC as STALE_WA7_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC2 as STALE_WA8_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC3 as STALE_WA9_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_EN as STALE_W10_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_FLOAT as STALE_W11_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_INT as STALE_W12_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_INT2 as STALE_W13_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WIDOCZNOSC as STALE_W14_134_0_ from STALE stale0_ where stale0_.STALE_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Creating new transaction with name [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2c0c9b9d]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - select platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOSC1_90_, platnosc0_.BANK_ID as BANK_ID2_90_, platnosc0_.EMPLOYEE_ID as EMPLOYEE3_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID as FAKTURA_4_90_, platnosc0_.FAKTURA_ID1 as FAKTURA_5_90_, platnosc0_.FIRMA_ID as FIRMA_ID6_90_, platnosc0_.GRUPA_ID as GRUPA_ID7_90_, platnosc0_.KASA_ID as KASA_ID8_90_, platnosc0_.MELDUNEK_ID as MELDUNEK9_90_, platnosc0_.OSOBA_ID as OSOBA_I10_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA as PLATNOS11_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DATA_KARTY as PLATNOS12_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_DEKRET_ID as PLATNOS13_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FK_NR as PLATNOS14_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_FORPLA as PLATNOS15_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KOD_SYSTEMU as PLATNOS16_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_KWOTA as PLATNOS17_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NR as PLATNOS18_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_NUMER_KARTY as PLATNOS19_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_OPIS as PLATNOS20_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_PREFIX as PLATNOS21_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ as PLATNOS22_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_RODZAJ_KARTY_ID as PLATNOS23_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STATUS as PLATNOS24_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_STWORZ_ZALICZKE as PLATNOS25_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_USED as PLATNOS26_90_, platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_Z_PLATNOSC_ID as PLATNOS27_90_, platnosc0_.PLATONLINE_ID as PLATONL28_90_, platnosc0_.POKOJ_ID as POKOJ_I29_90_, platnosc0_.RACHOTW_ID as RACHOTW30_90_, platnosc0_.REZERWACJA_ID as REZERWA31_90_, platnosc0_.WALUTA_ID as WALUTA_32_90_, platnosc0_.ZALICZKA_ID as ZALICZK33_90_, platnosc0_.ZMIANA_ID as ZMIANA_34_90_ from PLATNOSC platnosc0_ where platnosc0_.PLATNOSC_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Creating new transaction with name [ekoncept.service.PlatnoscServiceImpl.getRodzajTextForPlatnoscRodzaj]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7a494edf]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Participating in existing transaction
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - select stale0_.STALE_ID as STALE_ID1_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_CENTRUM_PRZYCH as STALE_CE2_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_KOD_SYSTEMU as STALE_KO3_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_KONTOKSIEGOWE_ID as STALE_KO4_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_NAZWA as STALE_NA5_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_RODZAJ_ID as STALE_RO6_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC as STALE_WA7_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC2 as STALE_WA8_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC3 as STALE_WA9_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_EN as STALE_W10_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_FLOAT as STALE_W11_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_INT as STALE_W12_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WARTOSC_INT2 as STALE_W13_134_0_, stale0_.STALE_WIDOCZNOSC as STALE_W14_134_0_ from STALE stale0_ where stale0_.STALE_ID=?
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Initiating transaction commit
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#402], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#101], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59905], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59858], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Faktura#141935], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59903], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Platnosc#59904], EntityKey[ekoncept.entity.Stale#401]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
2019-10-10 17:29:46 - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
```

Why Hibernate doesn't see value of field platnoscNr??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see changes made by trigger I added two lines of code in my service after platDao.save(plat):

1. entityManager.flush();

The EntityManager.flush() operation can be used to write all changes to the database before the transaction is committed. The flush() does not execute the actual commit.

2. entityManager.refresh(plat);

The EntityManager.refresh() operation is used to refresh an object's state from the database. Refresh can be used to revert changes, or if your JPA provider supports caching, it can be used to refresh stale cached data. Sometimes it is desirable to have a Query or find operation refresh the results.

Now my code lokks like this:

```
public List<Platnosc> createDocumentForInvoice(Integer fakturaId) {

   AuthUser user = loginMgr.getLoggedUser();

   Platnosc plat = Platnosc.builder()
        // I don't set field platnoscNr here it is null
        .build();

    platDao.save(plat);
    entityManager.flush();
    entityManager.refresh(plat);

    return plat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refresh the entity after save.
[See the link for refresh](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Persisting#Refresh)

Comment: @H Pat Thanks for answer. When I put entityManager.refresh(plat) in  my controller below findById I got "No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'refresh' call". When I put it in Service  below platDao.save(plat) I got "No row with the given identifier exists: [this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database#59935]". My service has @Transational annotation and I think it is connected with this. How to solve this?

Comment: @H Pat I found a solution, thanks one more time for help